# Failed while installing RED 5 Application Generation 1.0

Tags: java, eclipse, red5

I am trying to create RED 5 Application in JAVA EE perspective of Eclipse Mars in Windows Environment. I have installed 3 plugins:

> 1. org.red5.doc
> 2. org.red5.feature
> 3. org.red4.server

When I am trying to build workspace for same I am getting error

```
Failed while installing Red5 Application Generation 1.0
Details: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\anujak\Desktop\file:\C:\Users\anujak\.p2\pool\plugins\org.red5.wizard_1.0.0.jar!\build_red5.xml (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

While installing it is taking obviously a wrong path. I am not able to find the file from where this path is set. Any help for this will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: As the maintainer of red5, I dont know what you've installed from the example packages listed; did you install the red5 plugin for eclipse? https://github.com/Red5/red5-eclipse-plugin

Comment: yes I have installed these three plugins downloaded from here only github.com/Red5/red5-eclipse-plugin

Comment: After downloading these plugin. I have just made one change. I have changed `RequiredExecutionEnvironment` in each MANIFEST.MF from JavaSE-1.6 to JavaSE-1.8. And then I have installed all three plugins in eclipse. Then tried to create a dynamic web project while creating it gave me this error.

Comment: I just don't know enough about the eclipse plugin to help; the team member responsible for the app is not available right now

Comment: I hope he/she will be available soon. Is there any other way than using plugins to develop this application. I got this link:[link](http://red5guide.com/create_red5_application_without_plugin.html)  If there is any official documentation/reference link, please share it will be helpful.